# How to export data to xlsx using xlsxwriter for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am having trouble writing data to excel files. Running this code does not write the file to the expected folder.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Users\\hburk\\Desktop\\Python\\sqloutput.xlsx')
east = workbook.add_worksheet()



eastdata = (
        ['apples', 4.0],
        ['bananas', 5.0],
        )

    row = 1
    col = 0
    for pointname, price in eastdata:
        east.write_string(row, col, pointname)
        east.write(row, col+1, price)
        row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Edits: I changed the silly errors: eastres and east.close() - I tried to simplify this from the original code and mucked some things up. The code still doesn't work as written here.

Comment: `for r in eastres:` --> `eastres` is not defined, did you mean `eastdata` ? further, using `east.write()` expects the third parameter to be of type `float`

Comment: I tried using east.write_string() and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Just replaced `write_string` with `write` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> The code still doesn't work as written here.

If you fix the indentation it should work. I ran this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sqloutput.xlsx')
east = workbook.add_worksheet()


eastdata = (
    ['apples', 4.0],
    ['bananas', 5.0],
)

row = 1
col = 0
for pointname, price in eastdata:
    east.write_string(row, col, pointname)
    east.write(row, col+1, price)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

And got this:

[image]

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. Do I have to include something like workbook.save() or is there strange behavior with excel 2013?

Comment: Doesn't work for you in what way? There is sample code in my answer and a screenshot of the output. Also XlsxWriter has > [1000 cases run against 5 different versions of Python](https://travis-ci.org/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter) and they are all passing.

Comment: I've been using visual studio - not sure why, but that's the problem. Everything works just fine in command line. Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: It would appear to run in visual studio and would not return an error, but the excel file wouldn't be modified. The same thing was happening when I tried using the win32com package within visual studio.